# Register and Login API is not working in Laravel7 but without API its working fine through web.php

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, rest, laravel-passport

I am using Laravel7, Passport package, and Default Auth Controllers. on Web, Login and registration are working fine but on api its generating error.

Api.php

```
Route::group([
'prefix' => 'auth'
], function () {
Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
Route::post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@create');

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function() {
    Route::get('logout', 'AuthController@logout');
    Route::get('user', 'AuthController@user');
});
});
```

RegisterController.php ( Inside in default Auth folder)

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    
    return User::create([
        'first_name' => $data['name'],
        'last_name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'phone' => $data['phone'],
        'user_type'=> "abc",
    ]);
}
```

Api URL is  http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/register

Comment: It's probably a good idea to include the error you are getting ...

Answer (score 0):

try this -

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    
    return json_encode(User::create([
        'first_name' => $data['name'],
        'last_name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'phone' => $data['phone'],
        'user_type'=> "abc",
    ])->toArray());
}
```